# Merging multiple lines selectively?

Tags: files, scripting

I have a large file in which a header line is followed by a string of characters at multiple times. eg:

`file1`

```
VHBFBJBDSBVVFJBSV
SVJBVHJBVJ
SVKJBVJBNVKVJV
```

`file2`

```
dfhgdgffdghgg
SVKJBVJBNVKVJV
```

I want to keep the header file same, but merge all characters from line 2 onwards into a single line. can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Could you create an example of what you want the merged file to look like using file1 & file2? I just want to make sure I understand your question. You should be able to edit your question to make these changes.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `tail` to remove the header line, stores the results in .tmp files and then uses `paste` to merge the lines. The resultant file is ab.pasted.

```
tail +2 a > a.tmp
tail +2 b > b.tmp
paste a.tmp b.tmp > ab.pasted
rm a.tmp b.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want:

```
{ head -n 1; paste - file2; } < file1 > newfile
```

To produce a `newfile` like:

```
VHBFBJBDSBVVFJBSV
SVJBVHJBVJ      dfhgdgffdghgg
SVKJBVJBNVKVJV  SVKJBVJBNVKVJV
```

Above, the lines are pasted with TAB characters. If you want SPC characters instead, add the `-d ' '` option to `paste`, or if you want no delimiter, `-d '\0'`